# Can't comprehend "unknown OpenGL extension entry" error triggered by Haskell OpenGL program

Tags: opengl, haskell

I wrote the following program on Windows XP using GHC 7.4.1 (Haskell Platform 2012.2.0.0):

```
mkVertexShader :: IO Bool
mkVertexShader = do
  shader <- glCreateShader gl_VERTEX_SHADER
  withCString vertexShader $ \ptr -> glShaderSource shader 1 (castPtr ptr) nullPtr
  glCompileShader shader
  status <- with 0 $ \ptr -> do
      glGetShaderiv shader gl_COMPILE_STATUS ptr
      peek ptr
  return $ status == fromIntegral gl_FALSE
```

When run, the program aborts with

```
*** Exception: user error (unknown OpenGL extension entry glCreateShader, check for OpenGL 3.1)
```

I'm not sure what this error means, or how to address it. Can anyone help/

Comment: Do other functions outside of GL 1.1 work? Things like glTexImage3D, glGenBuffers, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have OpenGL 3.1 support on your computer. You have imported the function from [`Core31`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGLRaw/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-Core31.html#v%3aglCreateShader) while you might want the one from <strike>[`Core21`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGLRaw21/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-Core21.html#v%3aglCreateShader)</strike><sup>1</sup> or <strike>[`ARB.ShaderObjects`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGLRaw/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-ARB-ShaderObjects.html#v%3aglCreateShaderObject)</strike><sup>2</sup>. You need to check whether your graphics card supports the various versions/extensions when starting the application, and especially that you aren't requesting an OpenGL profile that you don't support.

If you use the Haskell `OpenGL` library instead of `OpenGLRaw`, this distinction is taken care of for you automatically.

<sup>1</sup>Well, the function hasn't changed between `Core21` and `Core31` so using the old version won't help

<sup>2</sup>You should never use `ARB_shader_objects`.

Comment: You should never use ARB_shader_objects.

Comment: Well, if your graphics card doesn't support OpenGL 2.1, what other choice is there?

Comment: If your card doesn't support GL 2.1, odds are good that its an old Intel card that doesn't support GLSL well at all, even with the extension.